# AsyncTask UI Update

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am tried to search about AsyncTack. How to Update UI after asyntack execute. 
Example : I have 2 java file.

file 1 : Myfragment.java, file 2 : MyAsyntack.java

in this case, i'm execute MyAsyntack on MyFragment. after Execute, I want to update UI.

On MyAsyntack, I'am updating database (doing in background). Any body can help?

Comment: Show some code, so we know what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an interface in AsyncTask and call it in onPostExecute of it to update UI.

```
public inteface UpdateUI()
{
    public void update();
}
```

then in your AsyncTask declare an updateUI like this:

```
UpdateUI updater;
public MyAsyntack (UpdateUI updater)
{
    this.updater = updater;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    updater.update();
}
```

and finally in your activity:

```
 MyAsyntack myAsyncTask = new MyAsyntack(new UpdateUI(){
                    //how you want to update UI
                    }
                    );
myAsyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: thanks so much, its work. I'm try to change UpdateUI to Thread is work too

Comment: @Rahmanza, It would be nice to _accept_ an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

doInBackground() is on worker thread and can be used to do heavy tasks like network calls to server.

When data is fetched, you can update the UI from onPostExecute(..) which is on the UI thread.

p.s. return of doInBackground will be argument to onPostExecute(..)